# for loop throwing out of range exception

Tags: c#, exception, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

The error is

> Index out of range exception

and is on the first line in the for loop:

```
for (i = (int)start, j = 0; i <= (int)end; i++, j++)
{  // Since linear relationships...
    idealWeights[0, j] = (female += 3.5);   **ERROR HERE ON THIS LINE**
    idealWeights[1, j] = (male += 4.0);
}
```

**The values in txtStart and txtEnd are:
txtStart = 36
txtEnd = 96**

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class frmMain : Form
{
    private TextBox txtStart;
    private TextBox txtEnd;
    private ListBox lstResults;
    private Button btnClose;
    private Label label1;
    private Label label2;
    private Button btnCalc;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
            this.btnCalc = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txtStart = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtEnd = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lstResults = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnCalc
            // 
            this.btnCalc.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 197);
            this.btnCalc.Name = "btnCalc";
            this.btnCalc.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnCalc.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnCalc.Text = "Ca&lculate";
            this.btnCalc.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnCalc.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCalc_Click);
            // 
            // txtStart
            // 
            this.txtStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(172, 12);
            this.txtStart.Name = "txtStart";
            this.txtStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtStart.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // txtEnd
            // 
            this.txtEnd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(172, 38);
            this.txtEnd.Name = "txtEnd";
            this.txtEnd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtEnd.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // lstResults
            // 
            this.lstResults.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.lstResults.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 96);
            this.lstResults.Name = "lstResults";
            this.lstResults.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(246, 95);
            this.lstResults.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // btnClose
            // 
            this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 197);
            this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
            this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnClose.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnClose.Text = "&Close";
            this.btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 12);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 20);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.label1.Text = "Start:";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 38);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 20);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label2.Text = "End:";
            this.label2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            // 
            // frmMain
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lstResults);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtEnd);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtStart);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnCalc);
            this.Name = "frmMain";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

    }

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        frmMain main = new frmMain();
        Application.Run(main);
    }

    const double MININCHES = 36;
    const double MAXINCHES = 96;

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool flag;
        int i;
        int j;
        double start;
        double end;
        double male;
        double female;
        double[,] idealWeights;
        string buff;

        //============================== Input ===============================================
        flag = double.TryParse(txtStart.Text, out start);  // Table start
        if (flag == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Numeric only.");
            txtStart.Focus();
            return;
        }

        flag = double.TryParse(txtEnd.Text, out end);  // Table end
        if (flag == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Numeric only.");
            txtEnd.Focus();
            return;
        }

        //============================= Validate input ==============================================
        if (start < MININCHES || start > MAXINCHES)  // Check table limits
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Table can only span " + MININCHES.ToString() + " to " +
                MAXINCHES + " inches.");
            txtStart.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (end < MININCHES || end > MAXINCHES)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Table can only span " + MININCHES.ToString() +
                " to " + MAXINCHES + " inches.");
            txtEnd.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (end <= start)       // Can we display anything
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Starting value must be less than ending value");
            txtStart.Focus();
            return;
        }
        // Define the array for table data
        idealWeights = new double[2, (int)(end - start) + 1];

        //=============================== Process ====================================================
        start--;                // This is the new line
        female = 3.5 * start - 108;  // Set initial table values
        male = 4.0 * start - 128;

        for (i = (int)start, j = 0; i <= (int)end; i++, j++)
        {  // Since linear relationships...
            idealWeights[0, j] = (female += 3.5);
            idealWeights[1, j] = (male += 4.0);
        }
        //================================ Display step ==============================================
        for (i = (int)start, j = 0; i <= (int)end; i++, j++)
        {
            buff = String.Format("{0,5}{1,15}{2,15}", i, idealWeights[0, j], idealWeights[1, j]);
            lstResults.Items.Add(buff);
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to programming so I'm a bit lost here, this code is from a book and there haven't been any error's yet in the book. So hope it's not very complicated the error because I'm still just typing alot of code and reading code to try to understand it.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger; it should be rather obvious at that point.

Comment: As stated by the error, the array index is out of range.  You're trying to reference an element which isn't in the array.  Examine the value of `j` when this happens, and examine the contents of the array.

Comment: Please give the values you put into txtStart and txtEnd.

Comment: @KaiHartmann txtStart = 36 txtEnd = 96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got no bondary checking on the `j` variable. It's obviously increasing past the size of the second array element.  As Servy pointed out in our comments, it's a common off by one error. I have adjusted the code to remove the = from the <=.

The for line needs to look something like...

```
for (i = (int)start, j = 0; i < (int)end; i++, j++)
```

Comment: The checks on `i` are there to ensure that `j` isn't incremented more than it should be, so no, he shouldn't need to add something like this.

Comment: @Servy That is not what is happening, though. I've pasted this code in an run it. J is blowing up because j is == the upper bound of the array. I cannot say what the checks on i are supposed to do; as this is some pretty awful code. Never-the-less, that is what is happening.

Comment: The checks on `i` may indeed be incorrect, and require updating, but the point is those should be fixed.  If you add in a new check on `j` then you're just defeating the purpose of the check on `i`, which is there specifically to do bounds checking on the array.  I agree the code is poorly written, but if you're going to change it, go all the way.  If you want to bounds check on `j` then just remove the two loop variable code entirely and use a more traditional `for` loop.

Comment: To your edit, you're now one less than the size of the array, rather than the OP's code which is one too many.

Comment: @Servy I agree. It makes the checks on i redundant. They aren't needed in the first place. This is a pretty poor example of C#; both idiomatically and logically. Based on this code sample, I certainly wouldn't recommend this book to anyone.

Comment: @Servy You are absolutely right; but fixing this code in a more correct way could take a fair amount of time. The edit "makes it work"; and was just a clarification of what I had before.

Comment: They *were* needed (given that approach).  The code was mostly right, it just had an off by one error.  If it was changed to < rather than <= it would have been fine.  Confusing and hard to read, but working.  The intent is to have the `for` loop count from the lower bound to the upper bound, but have a second loop variable counting up from zero alongside it.  If you're going to re-write it then just loop from 0 to `idealWeights.GetLength(1)` so you don't need to worry about calculating the proper end state. That how I'd write that loop. You can then add `start` to the loop variable if needed.

Comment: @Servy I've never seen anyone do a control variable for another variable before, so I didn't catch that. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @JohnKraft Thanks for the help. Your the best. The code is working.